# Lambda within VPC can't connect to internet outside of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-elasticsearch

I have a Lambda function deployed inside my VPC in order for it to talk to Elasticsearch (which it does fine.) As with many other similar questions about this on SO, I need it to talk to S3 and some other websites out there on the internet to download data from. I've followed all the guides - my Lambda is in a private subnet that sends 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to my NAT Gateway, which lives inside a public subnet that sends all 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to an internet gateway. Really scratching my hard vigorously as to why this isn't working for me.

Here is the network settings of my lambda:
[Lambda Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7ZCS.png)

Here is the settings of my private subnet that shows that 0.0.0.0/0 traffic is directed to my NAT gateway:
[Private subnet route table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NzqS.png)

Settings of my public subnet that shows that 0.0.0.0/0 traffic is directed to my Internet gateway:
[Public subnet route table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wErw.png)

Finally, my NAT gateway settings that is showing that its connected to the public subnet:
[NAT settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkckH.png)

Thanks in advance everyone, would really appreciate any thoughts to where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Your setup does seem correct, though I am confused by what I see in the outbound rules.  Is that first rule the default rule that allows all traffic?

Comment: The first step is to determine whether the Lambda function can access the Internet. Can you try a simple Lambda function that uses `import urllib.request` and within the handler uses `print(urllib.request.urlopen('https://wikipedia.com').read())`? It should show the page contents in the debug output. You can try this _without_ the function connected to a VPC to prove that it works, then try it again when connected to the VPC to see if it gets the same result.

Comment: To debug the networking blackbox of lambda, consider using an existing or spinning an ec2 free instance. Check the connectivity and get rid of the box if required.

Comment: hey, don't what you're using for lambda, but there must be an exec for your language. Try doing exec('tracepath google.com') and check the output.